# GridEngine on single machine: How can I limit cores for each job?

Tags: sungridengine

I have a single machine with 32 cores (2 processors), and 32G RAM. I installed gridengine to submit jobs to those queues I created. But it seems jobs are running on all cores.

I wonder if there is way to limit cores and RAMs for each job. For example I have two queues: parallel.q and serial.q, so that I allocate 20G RAMS and 20 cores to serial.q but I want each job only use one core and maximum 1G RAMs, and 8G RAMs + 8 cores to a single parallel job. All 4 cores and 4G rams left for other usage.

How can I config my queue or gridengine to get the setting right? I tried to read the manual, but don't have a clue.

Thanks!

> I don't have problem with parallel jobs. I have some serial jobs will call several different programs somehow the system will assign them all cores available. But I don't want all cores be used for jobs rather for example only two cores available for each job.(Each job has several programs run sequentially, in which case systems allocate each program a core). BTW, I would like have some idle cores all the time to process other jobs, like processing data. Is it possible or necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, if I understand well, you want to partition a single machine with several sub-queues, is that right?

This may be problematic with SGE because the host configuration allows you to set the number of CPU available on a given node. Than you create your queues and assign different hosts to different queues.

In your case, you shoud assign the same host to one master queue, and then add subordinate queues that can use only a given `MAX_SLOTS` slots.

But if I may ask one question: why should you partition it? If you set up only one queue and configure some parallel environment then you can just submit your jobs using `qsub -pe <parallelEnvironment> <NSLOTS>` and the grid engine takes care of everything. I suggest you setup at least an OpenMP parallel environment, because you won't probably need MPI on a shared memory machine like yours (it seems a great machine BTW).

Another thing is that you must be able to configure your model run so that the code that you are using can be used with a limited number of CPU; this is **very important**. In practice you must assign the same number of CPUs to the simulation code than to the SGE. This information is contained in the `$NSLOTS` variable of your qsub-script.

Comment: OK, first of all to leave some cpu "free" from SGE: You can leave several cores outside the gridengine knowledge, just configure your queue with less cores than what you have in the machine. Example, if you have 32 cores and you want the grid engine to "know" only 30 you just have to put 30 as `slots` in the queue configuration file when you modify it with `qconf -mq <queue_name>` .

Comment: Secondly, sorry: I can't understand your english in your comment here above... What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks. I think I know how to do it.